# How to Preserve variable spacing in FTP command in BASH?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ftp

Hi here is what i am trying to do

```
string='quote site LRECL=4096 - quote site RECFM=VB'
echo $string | sed s/-/\\n/g
```

Output is:

```
quote site LRECL=4096 
quote site RECFM=VB
```

But when i try doing FTP as:

```
ftp_f=`ftp -vni $ADDRESS <<EOF > log_fil
user $USER $PASS
$string | sed s/-/\\n/g
bye
EOF`
```

It does not create newline here so it executes only one `quote site` command when I need to execute as many of them as there are in the string variable. I tried storing `echo $string | sed s/-/\\n/g` in  a new variable to call it with quotes as `"$string2"` within FTP ,but FTP does not recognize it.
Please tell me what to do ?

Comment: Does `string=$'quote site LRECL=4096\nquote site RECFM=VB'` and then just using `$string` in the heredoc work?

Comment: Q: is the goal to run **sed** on a remote **ftp** server, or is **sed** to run locally in **bash**?

Comment: @agc I want to run it on a remote ftp.because if i run it locally and i dont know how many times it needs that site command so declaring that many variable would not be possible.

Comment: @EtanReisner i tried using \n in string even that does not work

Comment: @agc goal is to run those many site commands in ftp server, how to do that with sed on local or remote does not matter for me, tell me if there can be a better way.

Comment: @msj003, see my answer below (not in comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The problem may not need **sed**, first try this:

```
string="user $USER $PASS
quote site LRECL=4096
quote site RECFM=VB
bye
"

ftp_f=`echo "$string" | ftp -vni $ADDRESS > log_fil`
```

But *if* **sed** is needed, read on...

2) To store a multi-line command in a string that can be output to a pipe, try something like:

```
foo="{ echo hi ; echo ho ; }"
eval "$foo" | sed s/h/H/
```

...which outputs:

```
Hi
Ho
```

Be careful with **eval**, as it can run anything (i.e. terrible things like `rm -f *`).  If any user input is to be used in a string that goes to **eval**, parse and check it first.

Avoid variable names that are also command names.  There's already a **string** command.